# Add UIGestureRecognizer to CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I want to add an UIGestureRecognizer to CollectionViewCell class, in CollectionViewCell drawRect method, i have:

```
//Add swipeGestureGecognizer
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* swipeRightGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipeRightGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGestureRecognizer];

- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
  NSLog(@"swipe");

}
```

but i doesn't work, it seems like the swipeGestureGecognizer wasn't add to the cell

Comment: Not necessarily a reason it "doesn't work" but: Adding the gesture recognizer in the `drawRect` method is probably the wrong place (`drawRect` is called multiple times very frequently and you'll end up with multiple gesture recognizers).  The `init` method would be better.

Comment: I tried both, they don't work cause nothing is printed

Comment: I would put it in whatever init method you have for the custom cell and make sure that gesture creation and add code is actually executing.  Put a breakpoint or NSLog right before the addGestureRecognizer line.

Comment: Probably you chose wrong init. Did you used initWithCoder?

Comment: swipeGestureGecognizer did adds to the cell, but it just doesn't triggered, i don't know why

Comment: Swipe gestures have to be added in both directions. Make sure you are swiping in the same direction that you are swiping in. Or add gestures for both.

Comment: @user2735868, The code posted should work.  There might be some other view or gesture on top blocking the gesture on the cell.